# Python create list combination

Tags: python, combinations

I have a dictionary contain element and sequence count of element. I want to create a list of list that combined from these elements

Example

```
Input: dictElement = {"PA":2,"PB":2}

Expected Output:
[('PB0', 'PA0'),
('PB0', 'PA1'),
('PB1', 'PA0'),
('PB1', 'PA1')]
```

---

```
Input: dictElement = {"PA":2,"PB":2,"PC":3}

Expected Output:
[('PC0', 'PB0', 'PA0'), 
('PC0', 'PB0', 'PA1'), 
('PC0', 'PB1', 'PA0'), 
('PC0', 'PB1', 'PA1'), 
('PC1', 'PB0', 'PA0'), 
('PC1', 'PB0', 'PA1'), 
('PC1', 'PB1', 'PA0'), 
('PC1', 'PB1', 'PA1'), 
('PC2', 'PB0', 'PA0'), 
('PC2', 'PB0', 'PA1'), 
('PC2', 'PB1', 'PA0'), 
('PC2', 'PB1', 'PA1')]
```

Note: Number elements of dictionary can be change

Comment: have you done anything

Comment: Dictionaries are un-ordered. What 'order' do you want to impose on the keys?

Comment: Other than that, this is trivially achieved with `itertools.product()`; `product(*(['{}{}'.format(v, i) for i in range(dictElement[v])] for v in dictElement))`.

Comment: Sorry, I want to keep the order as example

Comment: @KenNguyen: *what determines that order*. You can't get that order from the dictionary, because that order is not guaranteed and trivially changes with insertions, deletions and if hash randomisation is enabled (by default on Python 3), on the current random hash value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified in what order the keys of the dictionary should be processed in the output. If one assumes reverse sorting order, you can do this trivially with `itertools.product()`:

```
from itertools import product

combinations = product(*(['{0}{1}'.format(v, i) for i in range(dictElement[v])] 
                         for v in sorted(dictElement, reverse=True))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> dictElement = {"PA":2,"PB":2,"PC":3}
>>> combinations = product(*(['{0}{1}'.format(v, i) for i in range(dictElement[v])]
...                           for v in sorted(dictElement, reverse=True)))
>>> for combo in combinations:
...     print(combo)
...
('PC0', 'PB0', 'PA0')
('PC0', 'PB0', 'PA1')
('PC0', 'PB1', 'PA0')
('PC0', 'PB1', 'PA1')
('PC1', 'PB0', 'PA0')
('PC1', 'PB0', 'PA1')
('PC1', 'PB1', 'PA0')
('PC1', 'PB1', 'PA1')
('PC2', 'PB0', 'PA0')
('PC2', 'PB0', 'PA1')
('PC2', 'PB1', 'PA0')
('PC2', 'PB1', 'PA1')
```

Comment: I meet the error: ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: @KenNguyen: that means you are using Python 2.6; use `0` and `1` in the formatting placeholders: `'{0}{1}'`

Comment: combinations is <itertools.product object at 0x7f7803456af0>

Can we convert it to list of list?

Comment: @KenNguyen just call `list()` on the iterator.